# 'Proper' Android Development Syntax

Tags: java, android

I am not entirely sure this is the right SE to ask this on but I am wondering if this is expected when developing for android. I am ending up with a larger containing class and then a significant amount of nested/newed anonymous classes for callbacks within callbacks. I am wondering if this is expected or if there is a better way of doing this as the amount of nested classes is starting to lead to very convoluted code.

This is just a dialog fragment that has some settings on it. When you click on a setting it populates a list view with the appropriate options and when you select an option it updates the value that you clicked on. It is a DialogFragment with a nested anonymous OnClickListener() that then assigns a nested anonymous OnItemClickListener() to a ListView type of object. This allows me to use the ListView object for multiple settings with having to duplicate the ListView for each one of them (I just bind a new adapter and OnItemClickListener to it).

```
class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    protected View     _root;
    protected ListView _listViewSomeSettingOptions;
    protected TextView _textViewSomeSetting;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        _root = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_for_dialog, container, false);
        _listViewSomeSettingOptions = (ListView)_root.FindViewById(R.id.listViewSettingOptions);
        _textViewSomeSetting.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            protected ArrayList<String> _someSettingOptions = new ArrayList<String>();
            // Fill _someSettingOptions with a list of options
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, _someSettingOptions);
            _listViewSomeSettingOptions.setAdapter(adapter);
            _listViewSomeSettingOptions.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
                {
                    _textViewSomeSetting.setText(_someSettingOptions.get(position));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this just how it goes? Should I be making custom controls that implement the listeners instead of using the anonymous ones? This DialogFragment is approaching 1000 lines all in onCreateView now handling the different options and display updates of a user tweaking the setting options and its just tingling my "Maybe this is not the best design" sense. I guess besides Upkeep I am wondering if there is a drawback to this form of development.

Comment: This question solicits opinions, rather than answers. Thus, my opinion: I tend to structure my code to avoid nasties like the above. My `onCreateView()` and 'onCreate()` methods usually just contain the layout inflation and member assignments (`findViewById()`). Data is loaded in methods such as `updateCustomerList()` or `updateProductList()`, which contain the various adapter assignments, or interact with the `LoaderManager`. I tend to call those in `onResume()` to always have the latest UI.  If adapters are used in various fragments, I use interfaces to create callbacks, etc...

Comment: @323go Are you aware of any performance concerns or is this type of code mostly just heavier on the understanding/upkeep?

Comment: Each anonymous class has overhead... so if you use three anonymous classes in place of one reusable one, it would affect performance negatively. This would largely affect heap though -- after all, these are listeners, so they don't get called more than once or twice.

Comment: @323go That was what I wanted to know. There are other concerns with this type of code aside from maintainability. Thanks